# Improving performance of bulk UFW rule updates?

Tags: ufw

I'm using UFW to block countries like Russia and China that frequently originate hack attempts on my servers.

I have files of IP ranges for each country (in CIDR notation) and use the following to add the UFW rules:

```
cat china | awk '/^[^#]/ { print $1 }' | sudo xargs -I {} ufw deny from {} to any
```

This takes a LONG time, as each UFW command takes more than a second and there are many thousands of IP ranges to create rules for.

Is there a faster way to add batches of rules to UFW?

Comment: I honestly think that you're probably putting way more load on your system than the unsuccesful login attempts and port scans; every rule in your firewall needs to be parsed, and unless you have some early stopping criteria, every packet that comes through needs to *negatively be checked against every single rule*. So, *does this actually serve the purpose you intend it to have*?

Comment: I ask because it gives you zero security: someone trying to exploit anything on your system *specifically* will not be stopped by the requirement to rent a VM for 0.003 €/hour outside China or Russia. It does reduce the number of connection attempts your userland software sees, at the expense of having to filter very much in your networking stack. This might or might not be a lot of work for that stack, but my guess is that if *setting up the rules* takes what you call a LONG time, then that's a very large number of rules and your footgun is now smoking.

Comment: (such rulesets do make a lot of sense, for example when you're actually a router that connects a whole network of servers to the internet: then one dataplane optimized server doing the packet presorting certainly saves a lot of load in total. But it doesn't sound much like you're in that situation.)

Comment: Thanks for your comments @MarcusMüller. I have studied the IPs of hack attempts and found a very strong correlation with Russian and Chinese IPs, so I'm confident that blocking these ranges will improve my server's security, crude though the blocks are. I do wish there was a more efficient way of blocking a country though.

Comment: Marcus is correct. Ever hear the saying, "For every mouse you see on the kitchen floor, there are ten more you do not see in the walls"? You may see a lot of traffic from RU and CN, but those are probably from "wannabe amateurs"; You are NOT seeing the connections from then ten *real threats* who are laughing at your naive attempts to block by country. There are many good sites and books out there on hardening/securing your networked computers. Start there.

Comment: Thank you for your comments, but you present a false dichotomy. In my view, informed by my own experience, it’s beneficial to both harden my general server security and also to block rogue states.

Comment: You may want to consider taking the question over to [Information Security SE](https://security.stackexchange.com), though.

Comment: Hi out of interest, what did you end up doing? I was using a blacklist on nginx but I read that a firewall approach was better suited. I could pontentiall block them on the router level as well or define more rules on the nginx level...
I've read comments and agree with the main idea. Although would like to define more rules on the firewall level if possible. Ideally I could pass rules like this too: "[ANY_IP]_folloed by 'login'" etc...
Thanks